# gitlab merge request should not be solved by the requester

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I've configured my protected branches to allow push for "no one" and merges for any developer. But it seems to also allow any developer to solve the request. So the developer that added the merge request can solve it.

I know that anyone should just not do that but is there a way that gitlab forces to have "another" person that solves a merge request than the requester himself?

Comment: No such feature in gitlab as of now. Maybe suggest it on their issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

This is available in Enterprise edition as of a year ago:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_request_approvals.html

---

Option to disallow author to approve merge request:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/388

Resolve "Option to disallow author to approve merge request":

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/merge_requests/455

Prevent author from being an approver:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/merge_requests/560